Has any Scooby-Doo villain ever been motivated solely because they enjoyed scaring people?
The Scooby-Doo formula generally ends with the villain unmasked and some motivation for their behavior being explained—usually by Velma. This is usually a joke, since the villain’s behavior is absurd and not remotely the most effective tactic they could use to achieve their goals, though, of course, they “woulda gotten away with it, too, if it weren’t for you meddling kids!”
Was there ever a villain who didn’t have any “other” motive, and was just scaring people because they liked scaring people?
Ignore any of the times the “villain” actually was a monster. We’re talking only about people, here. Any of the shows, spin-offs, movies, etc. are fine so long as we’re talking about something reasonably close to the formula.

I found two examples, but in both of them, the people who were in it for fun were merely opportunists—someone else with something to gain was also orchestrating monster appearances.
Camp Comeoniwannascareya (2005)
(What's New, Scooby-Doo?: Season 3, Episode 9)
Camp counselor Grey dressed up as the monster to prevent the camp from being turned into a resort. During this time, camper Dennis also dresses up as the monster, but only because he thinks it would be funny. From the transcript:


Dennis?!
Hah! I got you! I finally got you! You guys were so scared! You should have seen the looks on your faces!
But Dennis couldn't have done it.
It doesn't make sense.
All the clues pointed to—
Zoinks!
2 Toxic Terrors?


Scooby-Doo! and the Loch Ness Monster (2004)
Fiona Pembrooke wanted her Loch Ness Monster photos to be taken more seriously, so she masterminded the plan. Her accomplices Angus and Colin Haggart, however, apparently did it for fun. From the subtitles:


Your sons [Angus and Colin] were trying to scare away the athletes... so they could win the Games.
It's not true.
We don't even care about the Games.
We just like a good practical joke.
That monster thing's the greatest joke
we ever pulled.
Aye, lots better than the hedgehog
in the toilet bowl.



It’s a shame that both examples are kind of like side-villains, but these certainly work. Accepted, at least for now—if someone finds an example where just having fun was the motivation for the primary or sole villain, or all the villains, I might move it, but this works for my interest.
